# Should an object "load" another object on its own, or have the other passed to it?

Tags: php, oop, separation-of-concerns

Is it a good practice to load another object from within an original object, like so:

```
Class parent() {

    $child;

    function loadChild() {
        $child = new Child();
        $this->child = $child;
    }
}
```

or, should the child object always be passed in separately?

```
Class parent() {

    $child;

    function setChild(child $child) {
        $this->child = $child;
    }
}

$parent = new Parent();
$child = new Child();
$parent->setChild($child);
```

Which is the better option, more flexible etc?

Comment: Even though it's just an example: it should be `private %child;` instead of just `$child;`.

Comment: @stereofrog, it actually is a general question - I am wondering if my habitats are bad :) I am, in the end, looking to set up bi-directionality between two types of classes.

Comment: I think @J0HN got it right - if you practise Test-driven development you will quickly notice that putting `new` into your collaborators is almost *never* a good idea because you cannot mock and stub them easily. Also code reuse is severly hampered by it. Dont do it. Have a look at [The Clean Code Talks](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=The+Clean+Code+Talks&aq=f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the situation.

The name of the second object suggests that

1. the `Child` instance will only be used by the `Parent` instance
2. does not need to live longer than the `Parent` instance

If this is the case, than the first pattern ([Object composition pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)) is the better one.

If the `Child` instance is needed/used at other places in you code, the second pattern ([Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)) is more appropriate. Dependency Injection is a more flexible pattern, if you are unsure about your use case, you should generally use the Dependency Injection.

Comment: You can pretty much use a Composite *Pattern* without using any `new` in the object graph at all. Composite *Pattern* is about *treating individual objects and compositions of objects uniformly.* What you likely refer to is just [Object Composition](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Object_composition)

Answer (score 4):

The second option is more appropriate. It's called [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). One of the main reasons to it is that you can pass any object that implements `child` interface (including mock object, which is important for TDD) without need to modify your class.

Answer (score 1):

Depence on what you want. If you are sure you do not need to change child ever you can create it in the object. Less code => less errors. But if you might want to have different Childs later this would be bad.